# Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [isActive] [from User where isActive = :isActive]

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a table of users made up of a boolean value of active users as shown in the following table

```
id | name | active
1  | john | false
2  | bob  | true
3  | jeff | true
```

On the above structure, I want to retrieve the list of users where isActive is equal to true.

This is my hql query

```
public List getByIsActive(boolean isActive) {
        return  getSession().createQuery(
                "from User where isActive = :isActive").list();
    }
```

I am retrieving it like this

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get-all-activeusers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAllActiveUsers() {
        try {

            boolean isActive = true;
            return _userDao.getByIsActive(isActive);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in fetching active users: ", e.getStackTrace());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And I am getting this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [isActive] [from User where isActive = :isActive]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:99)
    at com.models.UserDao.getByIsActive(UserDao.java:64)
```

Please where I getting it wrong in my attempt. I have researched but it is not tailored to the problem am facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to set parameter for named parameters : change dao method like:

```
public List getByIsActive(boolean isActive) {
        return  getSession().createQuery(
                "from User where isActive = :isActive").setParameter("isActive", isActive)
        .list();
    }
```

Comment: The method setPrameter(String, boolean) is undefined for the type Query

Comment: see  setParameter(...) @Francis

Answer (score 0):

As the message says you are not setting a parameter which you are using in the query and it doesn't know what to do.

It should look like this:

```
public List getByIsActive(boolean isActive) {
    return  getSession().createQuery("from User where isActive = :isActive")
            .setParameter("isActive", isActive)
            .list();
}
```