# Query not executing, throwing exception

Tags: jpa

I'm currently working with a JPA project from my university. I'm having problems with a Query, especifically a Method on a @Service class that receives numerous parameters.

First of all, I'm trying just to make the query work with a two parameters.

Here is the method.

```
@Override
@Transactional ( readOnly = true )
public List<Candidate> obtainCandidatesOps(String name, String firstName,
        String secondName, String passport, CandidateType candidateType,
        Area area, Country country) {

    List<Candidate> resultList = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Candidate> cq = cb.createQuery(Candidate.class);
    Root<Candidate> r = cq.from(Candidate.class);
    cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(r.get("name"), cb.parameter(String.class, "name")),cb.equal(r.get("firstLastName"), cb.parameter(String.class, "firstName"))));
    cq.select(r);
    resultList = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

While I try to execute this Query I receive this error:

```
WARNING: #{searchBean.fillCandidatesOps}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [firstName, name] [select generatedAlias0 from Candidate as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.name=:name) and ( generatedAlias0.firstLastName=:firstName)]
```

Where is the mistake/problem?

I've read this topics, and found no solution to my problem.

[Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [isActive] [from User where isActive = :isActive]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971685/caused-by-org-hibernate-queryexception-not-all-named-parameters-have-been-set)

[How to solve "org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944733/how-to-solve-org-hibernate-queryexception-not-all-named-parameters-have-been-s)

Answer (score 0):

As the 2 linked threads tell you clear enough (so no idea why you have "looked at them for 5 days" and not noticed this), you need to set the VALUE of the parameters that you have defined in that query.

```
cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(r.get("name"), cb.parameter(String.class, "name")),cb.equal(r.get("firstLastName"), cb.parameter(String.class, "firstName"))));
cq.select(r);
Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
query.setParameter("name", name);
query.setParameter("firstName", firstName);
resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: hey Neil thanks for replying. I did try this, but im getting no result , i mean, the list its returning with null . Of course, i did try this Query with a "name" that its on the Database to see if the list didn't return in null.

Comment: If you did that then perhaps you ought to say so in your QUESTION (which says you got an exception about missing parameters), since this answers the question. Then you DEBUG it ... by looking at the SQL invoked by your chosen JPA provider.